# How to launch python script for other people to run it on their machines?

Tags: python, docker, github, installation, launching

I made a game that runs in your terminal using Python and curses. Now I want to launch it so that when people visit the repository on GitHub they can download it and play it on their own machine. I have a Dockerfile but I don't really know if it is necessary.
How can other people install my game and have it running without any trouble?

#### Update:

I published the game with PyPI. You can have a look at it with `pip install BirdJumpExtreme==0.0.1`. I found this article really helpful: https://www.codementor.io/@ajayagrawal295/how-to-publish-your-own-python-package-12tbhi20tf

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty complicated question that can have a lot of possible answers. To start, I'd look into python packaging.

Here is a good guide: https://packaging.python.org/

This will help you get to a point where users can just run `pip install .` inside your source folder and then be able to run `phils_awesome_game` from the command line. Or, they could run `pip install phils_awesome_game` and it would download it from a repository (like https://pypi.org/).

Comment: Ok I will check it out. Do I even need to Dockerize anything then?

Comment: Docker is another packaging method, but it is probably a bit overkill for a pure python package. Docker is useful when your python program needs certain requirements to run, such as a locally installed database/redis/...

Comment: See here for a docker vs virtualenv comparison: https://dev.to/aaahmedaa/comment/1p8o

Comment: I didn't use a virtualenv though. Does that make a difference?

Comment: If you're not, I would 100% look into it. Virtualenvs are probably the best thing to happen to python in a while, and you will instantly become a better python developer once you have a handle on them.

Comment: Ok but now its too late to use a virtualenv in a finished project. Can I still use the python packaging style or is docker smarter bc I have that file already finished with all its necessary dependencies.

Comment: So I have to make my code a package? Is there no way for other people to just clone the repository or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can create your docker image with entrypoint of excecuting python file.
For example:

```
FROM python:3.6
WORKDIR /test
# install requirements
COPY app.py .
ENTRYPOINT python app.py
```

Then create the image:

```
docker build . -t game
```

Now run the game:

```
docker run -it game
```

Comment: And how can other people then run this image on their device or rather how can they access my docker build?

Comment: You can push it on docker hub and people can pull it and run it with `docker run -it imagename` command.

Comment: Can other people access this docker hub also via my GitHub repository bc that's where my code is published?

Comment: you can create a Dockerfile in you repository to people them selves create docker image or you can push it on docker hub and add it's link in README.md of your project in github.

Comment: Ahh ok thank you I'll just add the link to the docker image then